# Flask: Get the size of request.files object

Tags: python, flask

I want to get the size of uploading image to control if it is greater than max file upload limit. I tried this one:

```
@app.route("/new/photo",methods=["POST"])
def newPhoto():

    form_photo = request.files['post-photo']
    print form_photo.content_length
```

It printed `0`. What am I doing wrong? Should I find the size of this image from the temp path of it? Is there anything like PHP's `$_FILES['foo']['size']` in Python?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are a few things to be aware of here - the content_length property will be the content length of the file upload as reported by the browser, but unfortunately many browsers dont send this, as noted in the [docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest._get_file_stream) and [source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L2499).

As for your TypeError, the next thing to be aware of is that file uploads under 500KB are stored in memory as a [StringIO object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), rather than spooled to disk (see those docs again), so your stat call will fail.

MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH is the correct way to reject file uploads larger than you want, and if you need it, the only reliable way to determine the length of the data is to figure it out after you've handled the upload - either stat the file after you've `.save()`d it:

```
request.files['file'].save('/tmp/foo')
size = os.stat('/tmp/foo').st_size
```

Or if you're not using the disk (for example storing it in a database), count the bytes you've read:

```
blob = request.files['file'].read()
size = len(blob)
```

Though obviously be careful you're not reading too much data into memory if your MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH is very large

Comment: isn't http://stackoverflow.com/a/23601025/125507 better?  just seek  to the end of the file and you aren't using any memory?

Comment: *in the docs and source: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L2676

Answer (score 44):

If you don't want save the file to disk first, use the following code, this work on in-memory stream

```py
import os

file = request.files['file']
# os.SEEK_END == 2
# seek() return the new absolute position
file_length = file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

# also can use tell() to get current position
# file_length = file.tell()

# seek back to start position of stream, 
# otherwise save() will write a 0 byte file
# os.SEEK_END == 0
file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
```

otherwise, this will better

```
request.files['file'].save('/tmp/file')
file_length = os.stat('/tmp/file').st_size
```

Comment: `file.seek(0, 2)` should do the same thing without importing `os`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/283719/125507  seek to 0 bytes from the end of the file

Comment: Warning: if you try to save the uploaded file after using the `file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` option above, your uploaded file will be corrupted, or rather it will be an empty file. Once you have obtained the file_length value, add the following: `file.seek(0, 0)`

Comment: @DangerPaws my files are corrupted/empty but doing `file.seek(0, 0)` hasn't fixed it for me.

Answer (score 22):

The proper way to set a max file upload limit is via the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` app configuration. For example, if you wanted to set an upload limit of 16 megabytes, you would do the following to your app configuration:

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

If the uploaded file is too large, Flask will automatically return status code 413 Request Entity Too Large - this should be handled on the client side.

Comment: Okay,this is a good way. Still isn't there any way to get the image size?

Comment: this is good unless your system is on a small drive and you want user to upload any file size unless it exceeds free space. in this case, use file.seek() suggested by Steely Wing

Comment: changing app config may cause issues, if we want to have different limit file sizes on each request, like upload file = 2mb, upload photo = 500kb.

Comment: App-scale configuration upload limit is not a "proper way" only something you should set ON TOP of everything. But then still you can have different file limitations for different file purposes. Also you may have dynamic storage placement/enlargement putting files on different drives depending on size... etc.. etc...

Answer (score 7):

The following section of the code should meet your purpose..

```
form_photo.seek(0,2)
size = form_photo.tell()
```

Comment: I tried this. while both .seek(0,2) and .tell() returned the file size (in bytes), once used, the file upload would not complete and save the file locally. (I get a filename with zero size saved.)

.content_length, .content_type, .filename all continued to work after using .seek and .tell 

if I remove the .seek and .tell, the .save command returns to saving the file correctly.

also : when I attempt a dir(form_photo) the methods .seek and .tell do not appear, but do appear when I do a dir(form_photo.stream)

Answer (score 2):

As someone else already suggested, you should use the

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']
```

to restrict file sizes. But 
Since you specifically want to **find out** the image size, you can do:

```
import os
photo_size = os.stat(request.files['post-photo']).st_size
print photo_size
```

Comment: Now it says TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found. What should i do?

Comment: `request.files` does not contain paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can go by **popen** from **os** import

save it first

```
photo=request.files['post-photo']
photo.save('tmp')
```

now, just get the size

```
os.popen('ls -l tmp | cut -d " " -f5').read()
```

- this in bytes
- for Megabytes or Gigabytes, use the flag **--b M** or **--b G**