# Rejecting files greater than a certain amount with Flask-Uploads?

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, flask-uploads

Flask recommends the Flask-Uploads module for handling uploads. I'd like to reject any file over a certain size. There are a few solutions floating around:

[From the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/):

> In addition, you can also use patch_request_class to patch your app’s request_class to have a maximum size for uploads.

```
patch_request_class(app, 32 * 1024 * 1024)
```

[From this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15782516/4775902):

> MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH is the correct way to reject file uploads larger than you want,

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

# save to disk first, then check filesize
request.files['file'].save('/tmp/foo')
size = os.stat('/tmp/foo').st_size
```

-or-

```
# save to memory, then check filesize
blob = request.files['file'].read()
size = len(blob)
```

I don't see `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` mentioned in the official docs, nor does it even manually check the filesize like the SO post does. Are these two methods ultimately the same, or does there exist a (big/subtle?) difference? Also, does `patch_request_class` save the file to disk first to determine total upload size, or does it save to memory?

Comment: you accepted already! on check size limit. waste bandwith. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` is a configuration item for Flask itself, introduced in version 0.6
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads

> By default Flask will happily accept file uploads to an unlimited
>   amount of memory, but you can limit that by setting the
>   MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH config key:
>
> ```
> from flask import Flask, Request
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
> app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
> ```
>
> The code above will limited the maximum allowed payload to 16
>   megabytes. If a larger file is transmitted, Flask will raise an
>   RequestEntityTooLarge exception.
>
> This feature was added in Flask 0.6 but can be achieved in older
>   versions as well by subclassing the request object. For more
>   information on that consult the Werkzeug documentation on file
>   handling.

And from the flask-uploads source:
https://bitbucket.org/leafstorm/flask-uploads/src/440e06b851d24811d20f8e06a8eaf5c5bf58c241/flaskext/uploads.py?at=default

> ```
> def patch_request_class(app, size=64 * 1024 * 1024):
>     """
>     By default, Flask will accept uploads to an arbitrary size. While Werkzeug
>     switches uploads from memory to a temporary file when they hit 500 KiB,
>     it's still possible for someone to overload your disk space with a
>     gigantic file.
>
>     This patches the app's request class's
>     `~werkzeug.BaseRequest.max_content_length` attribute so that any upload
>     larger than the given size is rejected with an HTTP error.
>
>     .. note::
>
>        In Flask 0.6, you can do this by setting the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH`
>        setting, without patching the request class. To emulate this behavior,
>        you can pass `None` as the size (you must pass it explicitly). That is
>        the best way to call this function, as it won't break the Flask 0.6
>        functionality if it exists.
>
>     .. versionchanged:: 0.1.1
>
>     :param app: The app to patch the request class of.
>     :param size: The maximum size to accept, in bytes. The default is 64 MiB.
>                  If it is `None`, the app's `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` configuration
>                  setting will be used to patch.
>     """
>     if size is None:
>         if isinstance(app.request_class.__dict__['max_content_length'],
>                       property):
>             return
>         size = app.config.get('MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH')
>     reqclass = app.request_class
>     patched = type(reqclass.__name__, (reqclass,),
>                    {'max_content_length': size})
>     app.request_class = patched
> ```

So I'd say go with:

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

Comment: so `patch_request_class` is just for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 3):

`patch_request_class` was just for backwards compatibility.

From Flask 0.6 onwards you should use `app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']`.

I recently took over as maintainer of the Flask-Uploads project, and one of the first things I did was remove the `patch_request_class` in [this commit](https://github.com/jeffwidman/flask-uploads/commit/e7629d14132507e858157f509e61b730ab905092) as it does nothing but add confusion for new projects. Any old projects that rely on it should just pin `Flask-Uploads==0.1.3` in their `requirements.txt` file.