# Flask on AWS Lambda HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes

Tags: python, http, flask, aws-lambda

I just figured out that my flask app cannot handle a certain amount of file size while uploading through an http form :

```
HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes.
```

How can I raise this limit ?

Comment: You may be able to set a higher `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` if that's where the limitation is https://stackoverflow.com/a/31874493/4541045 - please add more information about your network stack (ie. are you using nginx -> gunicorn -> Flask or some other layout?)

Comment: It seems the problem is related to AWS Lambda. I've tried the same request with my app running locally and there was no problem. However when I deploy it on lambda I get this error.

Answer (score 2):

The size limit shared by you looks like of API gateway i.e. around 10MB. [(API Gateway limits)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html)

AWS Lambda payload size [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) is 6MB.

Both of these limits cannot be changed. I was not able to find any limitations for ALB so you can think of using ALB in your application.