# how to get the size of a multipart/form-data binary file?

Tags: python, flask

I am creating an upload system for my flask app. When I upload a zip file I can access it in my app with `request.data` . However I don't know how to get the size of the file . I've tried `request.data.read()` but It doesn't work . I get the following error :

`'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`

I've also tried `request.data.tell()` `request.data.seek()` etc.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to (hopefully) solve your problem is:

- If you don't want to store the file locally on your device:

```
import os

file = request.files['file']
file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
file_length = file.tell()
# file_length should tell you the size of your .zip file
```

- otherwise you could use:

```
request.files['file'].save('/tmp/file')
file_length = os.stat('/tmp/file').st_size
```

inspired by that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23601025/12165405) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get file size using jquery, then send the file size while sending image.

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

If you want to know size using python than you can use os module but you need to save the file first.

```
 os.path.getsize("/path/isa_005.mp3")
```