# find the total size of an email message using the email package

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I am using Python's `email` package to analyze some emails.  I need to get the total size of the email, including attachments.  Is there a way to do this using the email package?  The way I get the email.message.Message object is to do:

```
msg = email.message_from_file(inf)
```

I was hoping to find a method like `msg.getSize()` that I could use.

Would it be correct to just use the byte size of the input file (`inf`)?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such method; the result of `email.message_from_file()` is a parsed object tree, and the original file size is not retained in it.

You could render the object tree back to a string, but then you'd still not reproduce the exact original message size as the rendering could easily use subtly different but functionally equivalent output (such as the boundaries between multipart messages).

Since you have a file, simply get the size from [the open file object itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283707/size-of-an-open-file-object) instead:

```
inf.seek(0, 2)
filesize = inf.tell()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link posted by Martijn, I found this solution, which I think may be better than the seek/tell approach:

```
os.fstat(inf.fileno()).st_size
```