# Total size of email in python

Tags: python-3.x, email, imap

I am using the imaplib of python to get emails from a server. These emails will be forwarded. Based on the total size of the individual email the attachments will be dropped or forwarded with the message. But how do I get the total size of a email.message?

I found this answer, but it does not apply as I do not get the email from a file: [find the total size of an email message using the email package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217749/find-the-total-size-of-an-email-message-using-the-email-package)

This is how I get the email:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.imap_server, int(self.imap_port))
m.select("Inbox") 

resp, items = m.search(None, "UNSEEN")
items = items[0].split()

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    #TODO: get size of email
```

Comment: Do you tried with `len`  to `email.message`?

Comment: I tried that, len(mail) returns a constant number, in my case always 17. I assume thats the number of headers or something like that.

Comment: Also tried sys.getsizeof(mail), which also only returns a constant number.