# get file size of the file from the file object

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv

I need to know the size of the file based on file object

```
import csv
import os
with open("test.csv", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    print reader
    filesize(reader)
def filesize(reader):
    os.getsize(reader) #And i need work with reader for more details.so I must need to pass a reader or file object
```

When I run  this I got an output is

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x7f5644584980>
```

From this file object how I get the size of the file?

And I checked this site but these are not CSV attribute [size of an open file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283707/size-of-an-open-file-object)

**EDIT:** When I use that two inbuilt function I got errors that are

> AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'seek'
>   AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'tell'

Comment: @I told  that  into my question i tested in this site.It is not valid in csv file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size of an open file object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283707/size-of-an-open-file-object)

Comment: Can't you use the `infile` variable ?

Comment: @CristiFati It is not duplicates.Why you said that it is duplicate.Can u prove that

Comment: @bobmarti Its a duplicate because the best method in your case seems to be the one indicated in the accepted answer.

Comment: Use `infile` rather than `reader`, when you are getting the size.

Comment: @CristiFati I need to pass the reader into another function?that's why i need get the size based on file object

Comment: You can't do that if all you have is a `csv.reader` instance. It doesn't provide a way to access the input file.

Comment: After the last edit, the question has the appropriate context (which qualifies it as a non dup). But it's impossible. `csv.reader` receives an iterable as arg (it could also be a list). Why do you need to get the size from reader? If size is important, you could get it from `infile` and "forward" it tho whatever routine needs it.

Comment: if i pass the infile what is the differcence beteen passing the file and infile.To avoid that i need to pass reader.And size is important.And the main thing is to avoid that open the file multiple times

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os.path.getsize` or `os.stat`

```
import os
os.path.getsize('test.csv')
```

OR

```
os.stat('test.csv').st_size
```

Return the size, in bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this answer because it actually answers the question asked about using the file object directly:

```
import csv
import os
with open("test.csv", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    print reader
    infile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    filesize = infile.tell()
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `os.path.getsize`?

With your code:

```
import os
import csv
with open("test.csv", "rb") as infile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)
   print os.path.getsize(infile.name)
```

The size is in bytes.

Comment: @duan I need to pass the reader into another function then how i get the solution

Comment: @bobmarti, you can't access the file/path from the reader, it design to get an iterable, not a file, you will have to pass the filesize/file object to your other function.