# Python access a zip file using file bytes and loop over each file to save them into data frames is returning an error of file is not found

Tags: python, zip, bytesio

I am calling an API which will result in a zip file that might contain multiple CSV files:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

api_url = res.json()['export_url']
new_res = requests.get(api_url, auth=(user, pass))
filebytes = BytesIO(new_res.content)
myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)
a = myzipfile.extractall
for name in myzipfile.namelist():
    print(name)
```

I can clearly see the file names but can't read them into data frame each one of them:

```
for name in myzipfile.namelist():
    df = pd.read_csv(name)
```

The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File data.csv does not exist: 'data.csv'
```

I tried:

```
for name in myzipfile.printdir():
    print(name)
```

and read as csv but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is still zipped - you cannot just read the contained file as you would normally. Zipfile has its own `open` function for reading contained files. You can then read the data into a dataframe with pandas.

```
for name in myzipfile.namelist():
    with myzipfile.open(name) as myfile:
        df = pd.read_csv(myfile)
```

Comment: any idea how to extract the file size as well ?

Comment: It looks like `myfile.seek(0,2)` then `size = myfile.tell()` will give you the size (in bytes) of any file/binary object in python [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283719/11789440). I am assuming this holds for the file object created by zipfile, but I cannot test it right now.